# Simply loop over multi-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I want to loop through the indices of a multi-dimensional array.
What I currently have is:

```
import numpy as np
points = np.ndarray((1,2,3))
for x in range(points.shape[0]):
    for y in range(points.shape[1]):
        for z in range(points.shape[2]):
            print(x,y,z)
```

I would like to reduce the nesting and be able to loop over all indices of the multi-dimensional array in a simple one-liner. Could it also be written in the following form?

```
points = np.ndarray((1,2,3))
for (x, y, z) in ?? :
    print(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `iterools`:

```
import itertools
x_dim, y_dim, z_dim = points.shape
for x, y, z in itertools.product(*map(range, (x_dim, y_dim, z_dim))):
    print(x,y,z)
```

or
If you don't wanna use map write in this way:

```
for x, y, z in itertools.product(range(x_dim), 
                                 range(y_dim), 
                                 range(z_dim)):
```

---

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy mgrid, we can do:

```
points = np.ndarray((1,2,3))
xs, ys, zs = points.shape
for [x, y, z] in np.mgrid[0:xs, 0:ys, 0:zs].T.reshape(-1,len(points.shape)):
    print(x,y,z)
```